# How to make document.write to write from the top left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twig

This is my template file:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Quote Metadata{% endblock %}

{% block css_js %}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmequotes/css/bootstrap.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="metadata"> 
    <script>
        var obj = {{ data|raw }};
        document.write(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
    </script>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

and **base.html.twig**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block css_js %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is in my css:

```
.metadata {
        white-space: pre-wrap; 
}
```

And this is the html I get, when I see the code of my page from the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Quote Metadata</title>
            <link href="/my-quotes/web/bundles/acmequotes/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/my-quotes/web/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="metadata"> 
    <script>
        var obj = {"hello":"world", "Test":["hello"]};
        document.write(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));   
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the output: http://s18.postimage.org/ebcuii3i1/hello.jpg

The thing that I want to change is the first `" { "` to be displayed in the top left corner, not as it is - a bit down and a bit in the right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using document.write? You are introducing extra whitespace characters with the tags and indenting.

```
<div id="output" class="metadata"></div>
<script>
    var obj = {"hello":"world", "Test":["hello"]};
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);   
</script>
```

Also why are you not using pre?

Eric

Comment: Oh thank you very much! It's perfect now! I don't use pre because sometimes I have too long lines and I want when they are too long to be divided to the next line, too.

Comment: I have it in the .css file - `.metadata {
        white-space: pre-wrap; 
}`

Comment: so why can;t you add that class to the pre?

Comment: Yes, it's better. I will add it. Thank you very much once again! :)